# Face Recognition with 20~30 degree Horiz./Vert. orientations

Tags: algorithm, face-recognition

I have a data set of about 1000 face images, I need to use a face recognition algorithm that will recognize these faces, plus for a horizontal/vertical orientation of 20~30 degrees, the algorithm must still perform, which would be the best approach/algorithm that will help me in doing this task. I need to create a .NET api/dll for the task, I am thinking of using OpenCV and then wrap it in .NET. I need some speed that is why I have to resort to OpenCV unless there is something better in .NET

Any helpful guidelines are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in EMGU (a .net wrapper for OpenCV): http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @ZippyV, I would try that but my problem is half done with .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on the subject by any means, however I work in a graduate research lab with two other video and image processing grads and I believe they used the Trace Transform algorithm  along with a few other algorithms to do just that.

Here is a link that contains a couple papers to the articles and some example source code:
http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/#TRACE

Hope this helped!